# Field variable reverts to initialized value when printed by another field variable

Tags: java, global-variables

Cropped code below.

I'm working in Java and NetBeans. I have declared two String variables, **dbName** and **successfullyConnected**, as fields.

**successfullyConnected** prints **dbName**.

The line, *JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, **successfullyConnected**);* prints "Successfully connected to null" instead of "Successfully connected to database."

Putting the text directly in the parameter, *JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully connected to " + **dbName**);*, prints the desired text.

My question is, why doesn't it work to use a field to store the String? Why does **dbName** revert back to null when I print it with **successfullyConnected**, but not when placed directly in the method call?

```
public class ABMain extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    //Field
    ...
    private static String dbName;
    private static String successfullyConnected = "Successfully connected to " +dbName;


    //Constructor
    public ABMain() {
        ...
    }

    //Listener
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == item1) {
            dbName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(requestDBName);
            try {
                stmt = ABDerbyConnection.createCon(dbName);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, successfullyConnected); //echo for debugging
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ...
            }
            ...
        }  
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ABMain();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `dbName` is always null when initialized `successfullyConnected`.

```
private static String dbName;
private static String successfullyConnected = "Successfully connected to " +dbName;
```

I think you don't need static fields .

```
private String dbName;
private String successfullyConnected = "Successfully connected to ";
```

If dbName is initialize you can add dbName to message:

```
    dbName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(requestDBName);
    if(dbName!=null){
      OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, successfullyConnected + dbName);
    } else {
      OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choise one database");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because You are initializing your `successfullyConnected` text before the user input and at that time the `dbName` is `null`. initialize it after the user input

```
dbName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(requestDBName);
successfullyConnected = "Successfully connected to " + dbName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once initialized these values wont changed unless you are modified. They are not dynamic variable and there is no binding to detect the value changed.

```
 private static String dbName;
 private static String successfullyConnected = "Successfully connected to " +dbName;
```

You need to do like this.

```
private static String dbName;
private static String successfullyConnected = "Successfully connected to ";

stmt = ABDerbyConnection.createCon(dbName);
successfullyConnected = successfullyConnected +dbName; // See this line is added 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, successfullyConnected);
```